# Manga/manhwa about sudden apocalypse which had creatures coming out of spheres. The main characters are high school soldiers. Everyone dies in the end

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this a long time ago (2019/2020) so I might be getting a few different manga/manhwa mixed together.

I believe it was a sudden apocalypse where there were these purple(?) spheres that randomly appeared across the world, from really small to massive.

I believe creatures came out of them - so the main group of characters had to train in the army to fight against them. I think they were high school students. They used modern weapons, like semi automatic guns etc. Definitely no magic.

The manga/manhwa was quite dark, with themes of bullying and death. I read it all and I know in the end everyone dies in the main group apart from one annoying guy.

I believe the manga was black and white, but I must have seen the cover at some point to believe the spheres are purple.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "a long time ago?"  What year would this have been?  2019?

Comment: Maybe 2019/2020 :)

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: I believe it was black and white, I must have seen a cover which made me believe the spheres were purple.

Comment: Did the story take place in a modern setting? And did the soldiers fight the monsters using military weapons, or did they use magic, or have super powers?

Comment: Definitely modern weapons, I don't believe there was any magic in the manga. Semi automatic guns etc.

Comment: Any idea what the creatures from the spheres looked like? Do you remember about how many chapters or volumes this had? e.g. was it only a single volume and 5-7 chapters, or 10+ volumes? You read it in 2019 or so, but do you have any idea when it was published? i.e. did it finish about 2019, or was it a good deal older?

Answer (score 2):

Could this be [*Duty After School*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/64087/Duty_After_School) (AKA *Afterschool War Activities*, AKA *Afterschool Military Activity*, AKA *방과 후 전쟁활동*)?

> Class 3-2 of Sungdong High School was just like any other class: a
> mismatched group of individuals preoccupied with their crushes,
> upcoming university exams, and other ordinary day-to-day worries. Yet,
> when strange purple orbs rain down from the sky one day, the students
> find their lives changing beyond the limits of imagination.
>
> Capable of sporadic and sudden destruction, these spheres quickly send
> the world into a panic. With the South Korean military forces
> stretched thin, the government hastily enlists those in secondary
> education and above into the army. Now drafted into military training,
> Class 3-2 must abruptly set down their pens and pick up rifles
> instead.
>
> Promised that they will encounter little danger—and that bonus
> university points await them post-service—the reluctant students are
> coaxed into accepting their new duty. Marching onward with an
> apathetic and easygoing attitude, the class begins their military
> service, unaware of the grim reality that will soon erode their
> innocent, carefree spirits.

Note that this isn't an *exclusively* black-and-white manhwa. The spheres (and various other objects) are depicted in colour for emphasis.

> [image]